# Models and inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

Stumbled upon something very weird today.

I created a minimal project/application that can show the issue. This is how I did it:

```
virtualenv venv
. ./ven/bin/activate
pip install django==1.6 # That's the one we're using
django-admin.py startproject bla
cd bla
chmod +x manage.py
./manage.py startapp bla_app
```

in `bla/settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'bla_app',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bla_app.MyUser'
```

in `bla_app/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    super_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
```

Then, I run the `syncdb` command:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

And it's been created as expected.

Now comes the tricky part. If I replace the models.py with a folder called models, and create an `__init__.py` file containing:

```
from my_user import MyUser
```

(the previous `models.py` was moved into `models/` as `my_user.py`)

I then get these errors:

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model bla_app.MyUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
auth.user: Model has been swapped out for 'bla_app.MyUser' which has not been installed or is abstract.
```

Do you have an idea of what is going on here?

I found [that](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21411), but I'm not sure they're related

Comment: Partitioning of models to submodules is not supported (only for models) becuase of the way django works, this will change in 1.7:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4470
Check at the end for a "trick" on how to perform that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split your model into modules, you have to provide the [app_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) Meta Option. Ex:

`my_user.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    super_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'bla_app'
```

As @petkostas said, it will not be required in Django 1.7 ([issue 4470](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4470))

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338719/345290), which describes the process.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. It is just a pain to remember that if we rename the app for some reason, we need to edit *all* the app_label values. But that will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

Django expects your model classes to be defined in `models.py` itself, not in a submodule. It's going to try to create an instance of `models.MyUser` which in your case does not exist in Django's world even though you've defined it in `my_user.py`

If you're looking to define each model in a separate Python file, you'd need to create a models.py file that imports them manually. This will likely be hard to maintain if you start creating a lot of models in that app.

```
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    _models/
        __init__.py
        my_user.py
```

In `models.py`

```
from ._models.my_user import MyUser
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it would work, but I still prefer the `app_label` in the `Meta` class as @renan-ivo suggested.