# Is the naming convention in django mandatory?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

In Django you name your files like `models.py`, `views.py`, `urls.py` and so on. I wonder, if this naming convention is mandatory for Django. Will Django's functionality break if you place your models in a file called `foo.py`? I mean, only the import-line should change, right? Or is there any magic with this named files done by the framework?

Of course, I won't give my files shitty names; but I am just curious.

Comment: For the sake of anyone maintaining your project afterwards, I would strongly suggest that you stick to the conventions and use `models.py` `urls.py` and `views.py`. If organisation is an issue you can use `models` and `views` subfolders but I would really recommend sticking with the nomenclature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

views, urls can be configured.

- url: You can defined your one urls by setting `<project>.settings.ROOT_URLCONF`, and include your apps' urls.
- views: Import your views or use view names as you want.

But for models, there's assumption about the model module name in the django code and other third-party apps. (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/apps/config.py#L9)

Answer (score 1):

The best is to create modules instead for a couple of reasons:

- you'll keep it consistent with Django conventions making it easier for others to work on it
- you can give more descriptive appropriate names to your files
- you will avoid really long files

So you'd have:

```
- my_application
  - urls
    - sub_set_urls_1.py
    - etc.
  - models
    __init__.py <= import your models in here
    sub_set_models_1.py
    etc.
  - views
    sub_set_views_1.py
    etc.
```

It's a bit more involved for the `models`, you need to import the models in `__init__.py`. Another way is to have a `models.py` file and put your models somewhere else: [Split models.py into several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336664/split-models-py-into-several-files)