# Django Rest-framework: Migration No changes detected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, project-structure

I'm new to python and django, I'm creating a simple shopping app. I have followed all the steps to create  django rest-framework project, run the server and it works.
What I did is created a new folder called Models (deleted the pre-defined `models.py`) and created inside it many model classes in addition of an `__init__.py` file as I red and imported all the classes inside it.

When running `python manage.py makemigrations` it return ''No changes detected''.

Here is the structure:

`quickstart/`

```
 .
 . 

`Models/
      __init__.py
      model1.py
      model2.py
         .
         .
         .
```

`tutorial/`

`manage.py`

Here is a created class:

```
from django.db import models
from quickstart.Models.Product import Product
    class Image (models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image_url = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Have you added the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: yes 'rest_framework',
    'tutorial',

Comment: The models module should be lowercase - the directory should be `models` not `Models`

Comment: I changed `Models` to `models`, it worked, but this appeared `unresolved import 'quickstart.models'` and please could you explain why it worked

Answer (score 0):

try giving app name while migrating
python manage.py makemigrations app_name

Comment: Welcome to SO Shashikamal. I'm sorry, this is not even remotely an adequate answer.
This would be better suited as a comment. However, whenever you are just guessing solutions, always explain, what you try to do, not only say what to execute.

Answer (score 0):

[image: include in models.py]

a picture says a lot. If you name the file straight as models it will work straight, but if you want to use custom name like `models_1.py` make sure you import it in `__init__.py` file.

[image: include in custom models file]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336664/split-models-py-into-several-files) is a brief read.