# Django: organizing models in a package after migration

Tags: python, django

I have a models.py file with models in it. Now I want to reorganize these models into a package as described in an [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package). Can I do it with the existing models? How does it affect previous migrations?

Comment: This shouldn't change anything, but you can always run `makemigrations` afterwards to see if anything has changed.

Comment: Could you please tell me that, where we create our models after create this directory? ```myapp/models/__init__.py¶```

Comment: The answer you seek is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336664/split-models-py-into-several-files/37758721#37758721