# DJANGO: many-to-many relationship with additional fields

Tags: django, join, many-to-many, field, relationship

New to programming and this is very confusing for me... I have 2 models. Department and Crossfunctionalproject. The relationship between the two models creates a join table called Department_Crossfunctionalproject.

I have another model called employee. I want to add employees to the Department_Crossfunctionalproject table. How can I do this?

I've been following this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships. Can I not do this on the automatically created department_crossfunctionalproject join table that DJANGO creates?

I keep getting the following error:

```
CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text) 
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
companydatabase.membership:"Department_crossfunctionalproject" has a relationship with model <class 'companydatabase.models.Department_crossfunctionalproject'>, 
which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

MODELS:

```
class Crossfunctionalproject(models.Model):
    nameofproject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nameofproject

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Crossfunctionalproject, null=True, blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    employeenumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='First Name')
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Middle Name')
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Last Name')
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Email')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Phone')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Position')

# db table created by DJANGO, I wrote out the model, trying to add extra columns*
class Department_crossfunctionalproject(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    crossfunctionalproject = models.ForeignKey(Crossfunctonalproject)
    membership = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through="Membership")

class Membership(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    department_crossfunctionalproject = models.ForeignKey(Department_crossfunctionalproject)    
    whytheyjoined = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: You have a bug in `Employee.title.verbose_name` -> missing `'` at the end.

Comment: thanks, that was an error made when copying the code into here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `Department_Crossfunctionalproject` before 'Employee'. Try with providing the name of `Employee` model as a string:

```
membership = models.ManyToManyField('Employee', through="Membership")
```

Comment: i moved the employee model above department_crossfunctionalproject as well as tried employee as a string but still I cant get runserver to work.. still getting the same error command in shell...

Comment: dont forget to regenerate your database. If you aren't using something like south, then you will have to delete the tables in this app and `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: i try to regenerate the database but when i run python manage.py syncdb I get an errors saying: Error: One or more models did not validate:
companydb.membership: 'department_crossfunctionalproject' has a relation with model <class 'companydb.models.Department_crossfunctionalproject'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Syncdb command creates the database tables for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS whose tables have not already been created.  It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation. 
If you changed the `Department_Crossfunctionalproject` model by hand you have to drop the table and run syncdb again.

[syncdb in django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

Comment: so I didnt run the python manage.py syncdb command to create the tables, I did it manually. But I dropped the department_crossfunctionalproject to try it syncdb, along with the membership table and I get an error saying: One or more models did not validate: companydb.membership: 'department_crossfunctionalproject' has a relation with model <class 'companydb.models.department_crossfunctionalproject'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

Comment: Some more typos.
Department_Crossfunctionalproject is missing colon on class declaration line.
Department_Crossfunctionalproject member in class membership can not be in upper case.

Comment: thanks, corrected those. Those were errors created when copying the code.

Comment: Department_Crossfunctionalproject `crossfunctionalproject = models.ForeignKey(Crossfunctonalproject)` also from copying?

Comment: When i tried syncdb i got different error related to field name clashes.

Comment: lol yes sorry... they were made when copying over, I had to mask variables.

Answer (score 0):

I like to manage changes to my models using South: http://south.aeracode.org/

Django doesn't handle dropping columns so I started using it for that.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error message, but the cause of my problem was different and hence the fix was different too. **My problem was that files that contained definitions of each class did not "import" the other class**.

I got the following error:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by bound method Command.inner_run of django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x010E2170
>
> File "C:\ ...\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 284, in validate
>
> raise CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text)
>
> django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
>   app_name.studio: 'instructors' has an m2m relation with model Instructor, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

I have a ManyToMany relationship defined between Studio and Instructor classes. Each class is defined in a separate file in models directory (not in the same models.py file)

**In app_name/models/studio.py :**

```
class Studio(models.Model):
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField("Instructor", blank=True, null=True, db_table="app_name_instructor_studios")
```

**In app_name/models/instructor.py :**

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    studios = models.ManyToManyField("Studio", blank=True, null=True, db_table="app_name_instructor_studios")
```

SOLUTION:

I added missing import statement to **app_name/models/__init.py__** file as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160579/models-py-getting-huge-what-is-the-best-way-to-break-it-up)

```
from instructor import *
```

Another way that I was able to solve it is to explicitly import Instructor class in **app_name/models/studio.py** file (However I prefer the firsts solution):

```
from app_name.models.instructor import Instructor
```