# Django, model split when a single model is getting huge?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've already broken down models.py into separate model files.

One of model file is getting huge, and I want to break it apart, but don't know how.

One way I can think of is, break methods into several classes (as mixins) and inherit them. but not sure if it's the best way to go about it.

- Edit,

This is different question than possible duplicates.

When a single model (such as Book) gets large, how do you split it up?

possible duplicates doesn't ask the question nor answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [models.py getting huge, what is the best way to break it up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160579/models-py-getting-huge-what-is-the-best-way-to-break-it-up)

Comment: @AbijithMg: I can't find an answer for my question, when one of your model (not models.py) gets large, how do yo deal with it?

Comment: You can split your logic into view, one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins sound like they'd solve your problem nicely. You can put another file in your models directory called mixins.py and do something like the following:

**models/mixins.py**

```
class BookMixin(object):
    def is_in_print(self):
        ...
    def calculate_cost(self, number_ordered):
        return self.price * number_ordered
```

**models/book.py**

```
from .mixins import BookMixin

class Book(BookMixin, models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
    title = ...
```

Then in your view, you could do something like the following:

```
purchased_book = Book.objects.get(...)
subtotal = purchased_book.calculate_cost(3)
```

Comment: One thing to know is that if you do this, your migrations get screwed up should you later try to remove any  mixins from the model class definition. Not a major issue, because you can empty them out down  to a single `pass` statement instead of completely deleting them.